# SSRS 2010 - Reporting Services SOAP API Insufficient permissions error

Tags: reporting-services

1. I have a report server URL - http://server_name/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx
2. I am trying to access the service using a C# console app
3. My console app code, with a service reference called ReportsService to the reports server, code is here -

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {

       ReportsService.ReportingService2010SoapClient proxy = new ReportsService.ReportingService2010SoapClient();
       proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
       proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
       //proxy.ClientCredentials = "";


       try
       {
           ReportsService.Schedule[] schedule;

           ReportsService.TrustedUserHeader trustedHeader = new ReportsService.TrustedUserHeader();
           string siteURL = null;

           proxy.ListSchedules(trustedHeader, siteURL, out schedule);


       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {

           throw;
       }
   }
   ```

   }
4. I get this error message on executing proxy.ListSchedules() -

> {"The permissions granted to user 'DOMAIN\user.name' are insufficient
>   for performing this operation. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException:
>   The permissions granted to user 'DOMAIN\user.name' are insufficient
>   for performing this operation."}

5. App.config file is -

   ```
   <bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="ReportingService2010Soap">
           <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
             <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"></transport>
           </security>
         </binding>  
       </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client>
       <endpoint address="http://server_name:80/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx"
           binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportingService2010Soap"
           contract="ReportsService.ReportingService2010Soap" name="ReportingService2010Soap" />
   </client>
   ```

Please let me know how to get around this error.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it by giving myself a Role of "System User" in "Site Settings".

[SSRS Site Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCLvT.png)

[Add System User Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkqpV.png)